# How to add a new column that has the same values as an existing column

Tags: sql

I need to add a new column to a table, and the new column should have the same values as an existing column. Is there an easy way to do this? The table doesn't have that many values so I can probably do it manually if necessary, but there must be a better way.

Comment: Can you share the DDL of the table and the column you want to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD NewColumn int

UPDATE MyTable SET NewColumn = OldColumn
```

The only problem is with NON NULL columns. You'll have to provide default value, update and then delete default-value constraint.

Answer (score 2):

First add the field to your table, depending on if you are using SQL Server you could use management studio to add or issue an ALTER Table command.

`ALTER Table MyTable ADD NewColumn varchar(25)`

Change the type `varchar(25)` to match the type of your old column `MyOldCol`

Then a simple update routine should perform the update:

`UPDATE MyTable SET MyNewCol = MyOldCol`

Update the values `MyTable`, `MyNewCol`, and `MyOldCol` with yours respectively.

Comment: If datatypes are compatible, obviously.

Comment: @cularis - I would assume if the column contains the same data, you'd want that new column with the same datatype no ?

Comment: @cularis - stop being illogical :). I've specified that they should be the same data type.

Comment: Thanks, that was really simple, I didn't realize SET could also take a column name.

Comment: @atrenk - If it solved your issue please mark it as accepted, i want to see what silly badge I'd earn at 10k points

Comment: @atrenk - now that was strange-I answered your question, you commented on how easy it was and it worked but you accepted someone else's answer. Boy i love stackoverflow